# Aplicar fondo transparente a un HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, iframe

Estaba usando un código de canvas animado con HTML, CSS y JS planos sacados de la web (link [aqui](https://codepen.io/alexandrix/pen/oQOvYp)). No pongo el código porque son como 300 líneas de JavaScript. Como estaba usando React lógicamente iba a ser complicado pasar ese código de Vainilla a un componente, por lo que termine usando un `<IFrame>` para correr ese canvas animado en mi aplicación.

La cuestión es que el canvas generado tiene un fondo negro que queda muy mal con el resto de la pagina, me gustaría que el fondo fuese transparente y dejase ver a la pagina de detrás, he probado varias propiedades de CSS para ver si podia quitarla, pero no ha funcionado. Las líneas de dibujo me gustaría dejarlas tal y como están.

La pregunta: Es posible quitar el fondo de un Canvas y que quede transparente? si es así, como puede hacerse? Les dejo una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que pasa con `fillStyle` a canvas 2d ?

Comment: 1/ un canvas de por si es transparente, el script lo rellena con negro al inicializar. quitando el fill del init, te queda ver que hace en cada frame, y ahi es donde el fill es con un negro en alpha ese relleno "casi transparente" es lo que genera el efecto de "trails" en las partículas. reemplazando el bloque de fill ( beginPath / closePath ) conun `clearRect` te deja sólo las partículas del frame actual sin el "rastro" de las partículas en el frame anterior

Comment: 2/ un iframe lo podes hacer transparente seteando attributos en el iframe `<iframe allowtransparency="true" src=elhtml.html>` y en el tag `body` dentro del html al que el iframe hace referencia `<body style="background-color: transparent;">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De comentarios a respuesta:

> 1/ un canvas de por si es transparente, el script lo rellena con negro al inicializar. quitando el fill del init, te queda ver que hace en cada frame, y ahi es donde el fill es con un negro en alpha ese relleno "casi transparente" es lo que genera el efecto de "trails" en las partículas. reemplazando el bloque de fill ( beginPath / closePath ) conun clearRect te deja sólo las partículas del frame actual sin el "rastro" de las partículas en el frame anterior

Esto lo podemos solucionar usando [`globalCompositeOperation  = "destination-out"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489751/1423096) para que el "limpiar frame anterior" no reemplace todo el canvas sino que afecta sólo los pixels ya presentes con un fade, el resto queda/sigue transparente.

```
  /**
   * Drawing with fade
   * https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489751/1423096
   */

this.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1; // fade rate
this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out" // fade out destination pixels
this.ctx.fillStyle = "black";
this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
this.ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"

/* comentamos el fill original */

  /*
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();
  */
```

Ejemplo del canvas transparente con una imagen de fondo en el `<body>` :

```js
/**
 * @author Alex Andrix <alex@alexandrix.com>
 * @since 2018-12-02
 */

var App = {};
App.setup = function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  this.filename = "spipa";
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  this.canvas = canvas;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(canvas);
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.width = this.canvas.width;
  this.height = this.canvas.height;
  this.dataToImageRatio = 1;
  this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  this.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  this.ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  this.xC = this.width / 2;
  this.yC = this.height / 2;

  this.stepCount = 0;
  this.particles = [];
  this.lifespan = 1000;
  this.popPerBirth = 1;
  this.maxPop = 300;
  this.birthFreq = 2;

  // Build grid
  this.gridSize = 8; // Motion coords
  this.gridSteps = Math.floor(1000 / this.gridSize);
  this.grid = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (var xx = -500; xx < 500; xx += this.gridSize) {
    for (var yy = -500; yy < 500; yy += this.gridSize) {
      // Radial field, triangular function of r with max around r0
      var r = Math.sqrt(xx * xx + yy * yy),
        r0 = 100,
        field;

      if (r < r0) field = 255 / r0 * r;
      else if (r > r0) field = 255 - Math.min(255, (r - r0) / 2);

      this.grid.push({
        x: xx,
        y: yy,
        busyAge: 0,
        spotIndex: i,
        isEdge: (xx == -500 ? 'left' :
          (xx == (-500 + this.gridSize * (this.gridSteps - 1)) ? 'right' :
            (yy == -500 ? 'top' :
              (yy == (-500 + this.gridSize * (this.gridSteps - 1)) ? 'bottom' :
                false
              )
            )
          )
        ),
        field: field
      });
      i++;
    }
  }
  this.gridMaxIndex = i;

  // Counters for UI
  this.drawnInLastFrame = 0;
  this.deathCount = 0;

  this.initDraw();
};
App.evolve = function() {
  var time1 = performance.now();

  this.stepCount++;

  // Increment all grid ages
  this.grid.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.busyAge > 0) e.busyAge++;
  });

  if (this.stepCount % this.birthFreq == 0 && (this.particles.length + this.popPerBirth) < this.maxPop) {
    this.birth();
  }
  App.move();
  App.draw();

  var time2 = performance.now();

  // Update UI
  document.getElementsByClassName('dead')[0].textContent = this.deathCount;
  document.getElementsByClassName('alive')[0].textContent = this.particles.length;
  document.getElementsByClassName('fps')[0].textContent = Math.floor(1000 / (time2 - time1));
  document.getElementsByClassName('drawn')[0].textContent = this.drawnInLastFrame;

};
App.birth = function() {
  var x, y;
  var gridSpotIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.gridMaxIndex),
    gridSpot = this.grid[gridSpotIndex],
    x = gridSpot.x,
    y = gridSpot.y;

  var particle = {
    hue: 200, // + Math.floor(50*Math.random()),
    sat: 95, //30 + Math.floor(70*Math.random()),
    lum: 20 + Math.floor(40 * Math.random()),
    x: x,
    y: y,
    xLast: x,
    yLast: y,
    xSpeed: 0,
    ySpeed: 0,
    age: 0,
    ageSinceStuck: 0,
    attractor: {
      oldIndex: gridSpotIndex,
      gridSpotIndex: gridSpotIndex, // Pop at random position on grid
    },
    name: 'seed-' + Math.ceil(10000000 * Math.random())
  };
  this.particles.push(particle);
};
App.kill = function(particleName) {
  var newArray = _.reject(this.particles, function(seed) {
    return (seed.name == particleName);
  });
  this.particles = _.cloneDeep(newArray);
};
App.move = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.particles.length; i++) {
    // Get particle
    var p = this.particles[i];

    // Save last position
    p.xLast = p.x;
    p.yLast = p.y;

    // Attractor and corresponding grid spot
    var index = p.attractor.gridSpotIndex,
      gridSpot = this.grid[index];

    // Maybe move attractor and with certain constraints
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
      // Move attractor
      if (!gridSpot.isEdge) {
        // Change particle's attractor grid spot and local move function's grid spot
        var topIndex = index - 1,
          bottomIndex = index + 1,
          leftIndex = index - this.gridSteps,
          rightIndex = index + this.gridSteps,
          topSpot = this.grid[topIndex],
          bottomSpot = this.grid[bottomIndex],
          leftSpot = this.grid[leftIndex],
          rightSpot = this.grid[rightIndex];

        // Choose neighbour with highest field value (with some desobedience...)
        var chaos = 30;
        var maxFieldSpot = _.maxBy([topSpot, bottomSpot, leftSpot, rightSpot], function(e) {
          return e.field + chaos * Math.random()
        });

        var potentialNewGridSpot = maxFieldSpot;
        if (potentialNewGridSpot.busyAge == 0 || potentialNewGridSpot.busyAge > 15) { // Allow wall fading
          //if (potentialNewGridSpot.busyAge == 0) {// Spots busy forever
          // Ok it's free let's go there
          p.ageSinceStuck = 0; // Not stuck anymore yay
          p.attractor.oldIndex = index;
          p.attractor.gridSpotIndex = potentialNewGridSpot.spotIndex;
          gridSpot = potentialNewGridSpot;
          gridSpot.busyAge = 1;
        } else p.ageSinceStuck++;

      } else p.ageSinceStuck++;

      if (p.ageSinceStuck == 10) this.kill(p.name);
    }

    // Spring attractor to center with viscosity
    var k = 8,
      visc = 0.4;
    var dx = p.x - gridSpot.x,
      dy = p.y - gridSpot.y,
      dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    // Spring
    var xAcc = -k * dx,
      yAcc = -k * dy;

    p.xSpeed += xAcc;
    p.ySpeed += yAcc;

    // Calm the f*ck down
    p.xSpeed *= visc;
    p.ySpeed *= visc;

    // Store stuff in particle brain
    p.speed = Math.sqrt(p.xSpeed * p.xSpeed + p.ySpeed * p.ySpeed);
    p.dist = dist;

    // Update position
    p.x += 0.1 * p.xSpeed;
    p.y += 0.1 * p.ySpeed;

    // Get older
    p.age++;

    // Kill if too old
    if (p.age > this.lifespan) {
      this.kill(p.name);
      this.deathCount++;
    }
  }
};
App.initDraw = function() {
  /* reemplazamos el primer fill por un clear  */

  /*
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();
    */
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

};

App.draw = function() {
  this.drawnInLastFrame = 0;
  if (!this.particles.length) return false;

  /**
   * Drawing with fade
   * https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489751/1423096
   */

  this.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1; // fade rate
  this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out" // fade out destination pixels
  this.ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  this.ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
  this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"

  /* comentamos el fill original */
  /*
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();
  */

  for (var i = 0; i < this.particles.length; i++) {
    // Draw particle
    var p = this.particles[i];

    var h, s, l, a;

    h = p.hue + this.stepCount / 30;
    s = p.sat;
    l = p.lum;
    a = 1;

    var last = this.dataXYtoCanvasXY(p.xLast, p.yLast),
      now = this.dataXYtoCanvasXY(p.x, p.y);
    var attracSpot = this.grid[p.attractor.gridSpotIndex],
      attracXY = this.dataXYtoCanvasXY(attracSpot.x, attracSpot.y);
    var oldAttracSpot = this.grid[p.attractor.oldIndex],
      oldAttracXY = this.dataXYtoCanvasXY(oldAttracSpot.x, oldAttracSpot.y);

    this.ctx.beginPath();

    this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + h + ', ' + s + '%, ' + l + '%, ' + a + ')';
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'hsla(' + h + ', ' + s + '%, ' + l + '%, ' + a + ')';

    // Particle trail
    this.ctx.moveTo(last.x, last.y);
    this.ctx.lineTo(now.x, now.y);

    this.ctx.lineWidth = 1.5 * this.dataToImageRatio;
    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.ctx.closePath();

    // Attractor positions
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 1.5 * this.dataToImageRatio;
    this.ctx.moveTo(oldAttracXY.x, oldAttracXY.y);
    this.ctx.lineTo(attracXY.x, attracXY.y);
    this.ctx.arc(attracXY.x, attracXY.y, 1.5 * this.dataToImageRatio, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

    //a /= 20;
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + h + ', ' + s + '%, ' + l + '%, ' + a + ')';
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'hsla(' + h + ', ' + s + '%, ' + l + '%, ' + a + ')';
    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.ctx.fill();

    this.ctx.closePath();

    // UI counter
    this.drawnInLastFrame++;
  }

};
App.dataXYtoCanvasXY = function(x, y) {
  var zoom = 1.6;
  var xx = this.xC + x * zoom * this.dataToImageRatio,
    yy = this.yC + y * zoom * this.dataToImageRatio;

  return {
    x: xx,
    y: yy
  };
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  App.setup();
  App.draw();

  var frame = function() {
    App.evolve();
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  };
  frame();
});


/**
 * Some old util I use at times
 *
 * @param {Number} Xstart X value of the segment starting point
 * @param {Number} Ystart Y value of the segment starting point
 * @param {Number} Xtarget X value of the segment target point
 * @param {Number} Ytarget Y value of the segment target point
 * @param {Boolean} realOrWeb true if Real (Y towards top), false if Web (Y towards bottom)
 * @returns {Number} Angle between 0 and 2PI
 */
segmentAngleRad = function(Xstart, Ystart, Xtarget, Ytarget, realOrWeb) {
  var result; // Will range between 0 and 2PI
  if (Xstart == Xtarget) {
    if (Ystart == Ytarget) {
      result = 0;
    } else if (Ystart < Ytarget) {
      result = Math.PI / 2;
    } else if (Ystart > Ytarget) {
      result = 3 * Math.PI / 2;
    } else {}
  } else if (Xstart < Xtarget) {
    result = Math.atan((Ytarget - Ystart) / (Xtarget - Xstart));
  } else if (Xstart > Xtarget) {
    result = Math.PI + Math.atan((Ytarget - Ystart) / (Xtarget - Xstart));
  }

  result = (result + 2 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI);

  if (!realOrWeb) {
    result = 2 * Math.PI - result;
  }

  return result;
}
```

```css
* {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #333;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/400x200");
}

canvas {
  background: transparent;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ui {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  p {
    //color: white;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    &.zoom {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      span {
        margin-right: 5px;
        border: solid 1px #777;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 2px;
        &.zoomin {
          padding: 2px 5px;
        }
        &.zoomout {
          padding: 2px 8px;
        }
        &:hover {
          background: black;
          color: white;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  span.zoom {}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui">
  <p class="zoom"><span class="zoom zoomin">+</span><span class="zoom zoomout">-</span></p>
  <p class="zoomlevel"><span class="percent">100</span> % - (<span class="width"></span>px)(<span class="height"></span>px)</p>
  <p>Dead: <span class="dead">0</span></p>
  <p>Alive: <span class="alive">0</span></p>
  <p>Drawn: <span class="drawn">0</span></p>
  <p><span class="fps">0</span> FPS</p>
  <a class="save" href="" download="capture.png">Save</a>
</div>
```

---

> 2/ un iframe lo podes hacer transparente seteando attributos en el iframe `<iframe allowtransparency="true" src=elhtml.html>` y en el tag body dentro del html al que el iframe hace referencia `<body style="background-color: transparent;">`

El attributo del iframe es `allowtransparency="true"`.

```
<iframe
  allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true"
  height="640" style="width: 100%;"
  scrolling="no" title="frame test"
  frameborder="no" loading="lazy"
  class="transparent full-size"
  src="https://test.empirico.es/SOes612426/"></iframe>
```

y el `background:transparent` se lo podes dar por class css o `style`

```
iframe.transparent {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Para evitar que se bloqueen los clicks/taps o eventos del mouse podes agregarle `pointer-events: none;` al iframe y/o al canvas (en el html dentro del iframe).

Ejemplo completo con un iframe puesto sobre el content:

```css
body {
  background: #006400;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-family: 'Source Sans 3', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
}

iframe.transparent {
  background: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

iframe.full-size {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p:nth-child(odd):hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fe0
}

span {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  font-size: small;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 1px 3px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

span a {
  color: red
}

img:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&family=Source+Sans+3&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <h1>el título</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent accumsan ullamcorper ex sed suscipit. Aliquam vel sem vel diam vulputate imperdiet et vel felis. Nullam porta purus eu metus ultrices, vel sollicitudin lacus blandit. Pellentesque habitant
    morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum mattis, velit et eleifend aliquet, nisi mi sodales lorem, sed pretium augue arcu vitae dolor. Ut facilisis, turpis in malesuada ullamcorper, metus nisl dapibus felis,
    consequat egestas leo arcu ac purus. Integer finibus velit ligula, non blandit ipsum imperdiet vel. Sed cursus nisl a euismod volutpat.</p>
  <p>
    <img width=400 height=200 src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200" />
    <p/>
    <p>Cras eu porta orci. Praesent lacinia, dui sit amet condimentum convallis, justo sapien rutrum diam, at condimentum enim ex et nulla. Suspendisse condimentum facilisis nisl ac commodo. Vivamus magna nisi, sodales at interdum vitae, scelerisque nec
      nibh. Cras venenatis sodales ipsum, vel rutrum magna consectetur ut. Donec tristique ex vel consequat rhoncus. Nullam vestibulum tempor ex id imperdiet. Integer hendrerit malesuada nunc vel tincidunt. Fusce molestie dolor dolor, eu blandit arcu
      volutpat et. Vivamus vitae iaculis orci. Ut non nibh ut lacus imperdiet pellentesque. Praesent quis mauris quis turpis sagittis gravida.</p>

    <iframe height="640" style="width: 100%;" scrolling="no" title="frame test" frameborder="no" loading="lazy" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" class="transparent full-size" src="https://test.empirico.es/SOes612426/">
</iframe>
    <span>forked from <a href="https://codepen.io/alexandrix/pen/oQOvYp" target="_blank">https://codepen.io/alexandrix/pen/oQOvYp</a></span>

</body>
```

Comment: Esto era lo que estaba buscando, gracias.

Comment: buena respuesta